# Downloads hang indefinitely around 55-60% after restoring from backup on new iPhone

Tags: ios-appstore, ios, iphone

My situation is I have been using iPhone 6s Plus for around a year. I just got my iPhone 7 Plus today. The phones are on the same carrier (Verizon Wireless) with different phone numbers.

I have iCloud configured on both to sync everything and store backups in iCloud. I told my new iPhone 7 Plus to restore from a backup of my 6s Plus taken yesterday. Although *some* apps installed okay, now all of my active downloads have been "stuck" around 60% through the completion wheel and won't progress any further. The *exact percentage* where each app gets stuck is **precisely** the same, down to the pixel.

[image: loading icon]

Rebooting the iPhone briefly resolves the problem, but I get a pop-up saying that not all my iCloud data could be restored shortly after rebooting. Then after a few apps are done downloading, the stalling resumes.

I know it's not my Internet connection because the browser on the phone is very fast and responsive on WiFi (and on 4G) and I get speeds around 25-30 Mbps with under 100 ms pings on both WiFi and 4G.

When this problem is occurring, installing new apps from the App Store just causes them to show the "empty" download progress wheel and the app never makes any download progress, no matter how long I wait (tried waiting 2 hours for a 10 MB app and nothing, but I could stream music at 320 kbps on Spotify no problem while staring at the lack of download progress).

Force quitting the App Store doesn't help.

Toggling WiFi / airplane mode doesn't help.

So this is really annoying... is anyone else having this issue? Is it something with Apple's servers, or if not, why are all of my downloads just hanging indefinitely until I reboot the phone? Could it be an issue with the phone itself?

This phone does NOT have the "hissgate" problem (tested with a CPU-intensive benchmark that made the phone quite hot).

Comment: This could be caused by any number of things.  You can try pausing all the downloads then clearing the App Store cache by tapping on any of the tab icons 10 times.  This will flush the cache.  Restart the iphone and try downloading 1 app at a time to see if they finish correctly.

Comment: I also experience this problem occasionally, when restoring from iTunes. Usually, rebooting both the iMac and iPhone, then performing a fresh Restore from Backup resolves the issue. The second Restore restores all apps and everything else without a hitch.